# Can we add external power to usb hub to power keyboard and mouse?

Tags: usb, hub

I have tried to connect a usb hub with external power as shown in the picture but dosent seem to power up my keyboard and mouse.! I'm trying to connect these two to my android device through an OTG cable.
[This is my mouse Logitech G600](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryg5J.jpg)!
[I tried to connect power wires with the usb hub's power cables what did I do wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBbGH.jpg)

Comment: You are lucky you didn't damage the mouse, hub or phone. As LPChip says, it is not just a matter of adding power to the wires.

Comment: Once again, what is this "a USB hub"? Model, techdata?  Your hub doesn't engage with keyboard and mouse, and you omit any information about "your hub". Does it work with regular PC? What kind of "OTG cable" do you use? Does your "android device" support OTG for host mode, if you use a pen drive? Does your "android device" support USB hubs?

Answer (score 2):

USB is a complicated protocol.

Just soldering in some powerlines won't do it.

Your USB hub needs to support supplying power to external devices with a higher voltage than what a non-powered usb hub does.

This basically means: if you want an USB hub that can power external devices, you will need to buy one that can.

So to answer your question: can you modify a non-powered USB hub to make it supply power to external devices? Someone who is really good in technical engineering (who would be able to build an USB hub themselves) would possibly be able to do it. But the average person like you and me, no way. Besides, the required internal hardware may make it more costly to alter the hub than to replace it.